# Need to compare C# source code with dlls

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, disassembly

We were using a product from a vendor provided to us in form of dll's. Now we are taking over that vendor product's source code. Our core application is dependent on those vendor provided dll's. We want to make sure that the source code that is provided to us is the same as of the dll's we are using. Otherwise our code can break and that could cost us big time. Can anyone please suggest a tool or a way we can compare the source code with dll's.

One way is that we can compile and publish the dll's and then compare the dll's, but that is going to be a huge task as there are multiple packages included in the base product including some aspx and html pages. We are looking for a quick and clean way to perform the task.

Any help 'd be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can try `telerik decompile` but I'm afraid that is going to be bit tricky....its not supporting all the things but you can give a worth try.

Comment: Decompilation will not make all job for you... Decompiled code is different a little, for example switch can become to ugly if then goto (so, you will have to compare side by side). I think there is no ready made tool to compare source code and dll...

Comment: If you are taking over development, your best approach would be to create Unit Tests running against both the compiled RTM version as well as the current source version. There's no quick and easy way for this task - at least not if you require to be 100% sure.

Comment: If you're oaky with manuell comparing you could use Dot Net Reflector for decompiling

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. It seems currently we only have option to compile the source and compare the dll's after disassembling, then have to compare both versions.

Answer (score 1):

For me the only good way is to ask the vendor to provide the compilation environnement as well as the source code (using a Virtual Machine for example).

Recompilling the source, then comparing the DLLs is the only good way.